# Rails controller code appears to be ignored for a custom route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I've got a very weird scenario where it appears that a controller action method is being ignored in a rails app.  I'm assuming this is not possible, but I need someone to help me see the "forest for the trees" :)  Here is what I have.  First a custom route:

```
 match 'topusers/:skill', :to => 'skills#topusers', :as => :top_users
```

Then in my controller I have reduced it down to the following:class SkillsController < ApplicationController

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController

        ....

    def top_users
        @skills = Skill.all
    end

        ....
end
```

My view has been reduced to the following

```
<% @skills.each do |skill| %>
   <%= skill.name %>
<% end %>
```

With this I receive an error of "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" on the @skills.each line.  I know there is data in the skills table and I can see that via rails console.  To troubleshoot I did a render :text => @skills.to_yaml and it appeared to be ignored.  This confused me, so I then completely removed the top_users method and still got the same error which confused me because I thought rails would scream at me for not having a top_users method.  I then thought that rails might be looking at a different controller, so I changed the name of my controller from SkillsController to SkillsXXXController.  This time rails did yell at me telling it couldn't find the controller, so I know it was at least looking at the right controller.

So, any idea of why I am seeing this behavior?  Does my custom route look correct?  Has anyone seen this type of behavior before?

Thanks in advance

Chris

Comment: are you missing an underscore in your match route? 'skills#topusers'. looks like you have defined your controller method at top_users.

Comment: Interesting, that was my problem.  I'm still surprised rails did not yell at me that the method was not present.  Thanks!

Comment: i believe that if the controller method doesn't exist, but there is a view that matches top_users, then an error won't occur... not too sure about that though.

Comment: i reposted the answer below if you don't mind upvoting and marking as correct, thanks!

Comment: Will do!  Thanks for pointing out the obvious for me :)

Comment: no problem man, those are the kind of bugs that take forever because they trick your eye and stay under the radar... that's why a good debugger is priceless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you missing an underscore in your match route? 'skills#topusers'. looks like you have defined your controller method at top_users.